# Replace first character with last character of multiple strings PHP

Tags: php, string, function, replace

I have this code

```
<?php
$str1 = 'Good'
$str2 = 'Weather'
echo $str1, $str2
```

I need the output as **Doog Reathew**

Answer (score 3):

Using the below piece of code solves your purpose. Comments have been added for your understanding.

```
<?php
$str1 = 'Good';
$str2 = 'Weather';

function swaprev($str1)
{
$str1 = str_split($str1);  //<--- Split the string into separate chars

$lc=$str1[count($str1)-1]; # Grabbing last element
$fe=$str1[0];              # Grabbing first element
$str1[0]=$lc;$str1[count($str1)-1]=$fe;    # Do the interchanging
return $str1 = implode('',$str1);  # Recreate the string
}

echo ucfirst((strtolower(swaprev($str1))))." ".ucfirst((strtolower(swaprev($str2))));
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Doog Reathew
```

Comment: @DummyCode, I have used `ucfirst()` ;) see the code closely.

Comment: how about reathew? is that possible? i only wanted the first letter and last but the mod edited it lomo.

Comment: @user3487504 remove the `ucfirst` then. See, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php

Answer (score 0):

just write below function ,it  will work

function replace($string) {

```
$a = substr($string, 0, 1);
$b = substr($string, -1);
$string = $b . (substr($string, 1, strlen($string)));
$string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - 1);
$string = $string . $a;

return ucfirst(strtolower($string));
```

}